# PHPNet & Symfony - htaccess and files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

My Symfony application is stored on PHPNet (don't if it's quite common for non-french developers).
Although everything in php scripts work rather well (except classic PEBCAK), but it's not the only web app on the server.

As we do not have bought any domain name yet, the application is accessible from a phpnet subdomain (such as p1234.phpnet.org).
Plus, it's not the only application on this subdomain, so they are accessible from *p1234.phpnet.org/abc* or *p1234.phpnet.org/123*.

Of course, on Symfony, you access the web folder and then app.php or app_dev.php.
Finally, the url looks like *p1234.phpnet.org/abc/web/*.

My .htaccess (which seems to be the default one when you install a Symfony application), rewrite links from **p1234.phpnet.org/abc/app_dev.php/bundles/test/img.png** to **p1234.phpnet.org/abc/bundles/test/img.png**. So on app_dev, everything works fine.

But, as my htaccess is written in order to redirect /app.php to /, I can't get the normal links with this configuration.

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

Options FollowSymlinks

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 RewriteRule .? - [L]

  RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_alias.c>
     RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

If someone has an idea to refactor my file so I can have the url for the images correct, that would be great !

Comment: `I can't get the normal links with this configuration` what are the wrong links you have? Do you display your normal prod page when you access the site p1234.phpnet.org/abc ?

Comment: I've edited my question with the real access link p1234.phpnet.org/abc/web/. The wrong links are the images I've set in my CSS. When the page tries to load them, they do not use the right path. Instead of p1234.phpnet.org/abc/web/bundles/test/img.png, they are "loaded" from p1234.phpnet.org/abc/bundles/test/img.png, which obviously does not exist..

Comment: The path should be `p1234.phpnet.org/abc/bundles/test/img.png` as the `web` directory is the directory of `app.php`. Maybe the problem is your `virtual host`?

Comment: Actually, the path should be `p1234.phpnet.org/abc/web/bundles/test/img.png` as the `bundles` is in the `web` directory. I can't access to the virtual host unfortunately (no access to the root user)